# Prefix reduce operation on Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Given an array say `a = [2,6,4,1,5]` how can I apply a prefix reduce operator on it.

For example:

Prefix sum of `a = [2,8,12,13,18]` or

Prefix max of `a = [2,6,6,6,6]`

I want a method using which I can use any suitable reduce operators like mean, max or min on the array.

Comment: Are you aware of `ufunc.accumulate`? As in `np.maximum.accumulate(a)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Just out of curiosity, any tips on how to use accumulate with mean?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I can't think of anything better than taking sums and afterwards divide by counts

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks this is what I was looking for. I kept searching for this functionality in ufunc.reduce and related operators.